# hibernate reverse engineering to include a @Transient property

Tags: hibernate, reverse-engineering, transient, hbm2java

I am trying to include following

```
private org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile photo;


    @Transient
    public CommonsMultipartFile getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(CommonsMultipartFile photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }
```

in my pojo class generated from database table.

I have studied to find there is a way to mention extra class code 
in meta tag like following

http://www.scribd.com/doc/23123635/30/Guiding-the-reverse-engineering-process

but this does not allow to add property variable photo.

Please suggest a way how can I do it in reveng.xml so that 
this code is included on every run of hbm2java.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve such custom code by using reveng templates. If you open `hibernate-tools.jar` you will find .ftl files in the `pojo` folder. You need to override them to put custom code.

Steps:

1. If you are using maven then put this under `componentProperties` for hbm2java goal:

   ```
   <templatepath>src/main/resources/reveng.templates/</templatepath>
   <filepattern>*.java</filepattern>
   ```
2. Create `revenge.templates/pojo` folder under resources. Make sure that the folder name is always `pojo`, otherwise the overrides are not detected.
3. Create `pojo.ftl` file and copy the contents from the `pojo.ftl` file present in the jar. Add all the import statements in this file.
4. Similarly, follow the other files to find out where exactly you want to put the custom code.

Comment: @DarthJDG Thanks, it seems to be working now what I did was I simply include the property variable in the meta class-code and even though the eclipse parser showed the xml error... the entity generated had the Transient method and the property both. Thanks!

Comment: @nightfly It's rdk's answer actually, I just fixed some formatting in his post.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no way to specify this in either reveng.xml or a custom ReverseEngineeringStrategy.

The way I solve this problem is by extending all of my generated base POJO classes with a custom class layer, and adding transient properties and special behaviors there. Not exactly what you were asking, but it works well and allows for flexibility without sacrificing the benefits of code generation.